# Start plot from origin in r

Tags: r, plot

I am currently trying to plot my results that I have obtained from a regression. I have added a line with slope 1 starting from the origin. Everything actually worked perfectly. My code looks the following:

```
plot(rfr_test_data$Y_Miete_je_m2, rfr_opt_pred_un, xlab='Tatsächliche Miete pro Quadratmeter', 
     ylab='Prognostizierte Miete pro Quadratmeter',xaxs='i', yaxs='i', xlim=c(0,50), ylim=c(0,50), asp=1,
     abline(a=0, b=1), family = 'serif', cex.lab = 1.25)
```

However, the line does not start in the left corner of the plot. The following picture shows this quite perfectly:
[Plot of my Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X2Kp.png)

Can anybody tell me why the Zero of the x-axis is not in the left corner of the graph?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems to be the aspect ratio. When I drop asp = 1, I get the expected behavior.

Comment: Thank you, @JosephClarkMcIntyre for your quick reply. It helped to solve my question.